# Einsteinian principle of relativity in the limit of infinite propagation velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

We can transform between inertial frames of reference using either the Lorentz transform in special relativity or the Galilean transform in the classical limit.

The Galilean transform gives: $$ x' = x - vt. $$

While the Eisteinian (Lorentz) transform, based on the postulate that the vacuum speed of light is a constant upper bound for velocity, gives: $$ x' = \frac{x-vt}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}, $$
$$ t' = \frac{t-\frac{vx}{c^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}. $$

With these equation fresh and ready, it is easy to see that we get the Galilean transform in the limit as $ c\to\infty $ of the Einsteinian transform, meaning **infinite propagation velocity** of interaction.

However, when learning classical mechanics, the Galilean transform just seemed very natural and intuitive to me, and nowhere did I suspect (or was I told about) that we are assuming infinite speed of interaction/information propagation. Where did we make this assumption in the construction of classical mechanics?

Comment: At what speed does Newtonian gravity propagate?

Comment: For completeness, one should also include the transformation equation for time.

Answer (score 1):

Already Isaac Newton formulated it:

> *"Absolute, true and mathematical time, of itself, and from its own nature flows equably without regard to anything external"*

Implicitly, this assumes universal time, universal simultaneity, which leads to assuming Galilei's transformation is correct (as a general transformation between inertial frames). In classical mechanics, this does not mean we assume all interactions have infinite speed, only that they *can* have infinite speed. E.g. gravity was assumed to have infinite speed.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of light does not have to be infinite, just large enough compared to $v$ such that the correction is small enough that we can't detect the difference. When $v$ is much smaller than $c$ then the first correction term is thus.

$$ \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2} }   } \approx 1 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{v^2}{c^2} $$

When Galileo was romping around he was using things like pendulums to measure time. And the speeds of things he was working with in his labs were things like rolling objects on inclined planes, so a few meters per second.  So his $\frac{v}{c}$ was in the neighborhood of $1 \times 10^{-8}$. So it would be pretty much impossible for him to have detected any relativistic effects.

So non-relativistic mechanics starting from Galileo didn't explicitly make the assumption. It just all happened in the range that the correction due to relativity was impossibly too small to detect.

Comment: Of course, it's not really about the "speed of light"... but of the "maximum signal speed".

Answer (score 0):

The reason Galilean (Newtonian) mechanics seems natural or normal is we live our entire lives, as did our ancestors for tens of thousands of years, in the Newtonian Limit of mechanics, $v \ll c$. In our experience: we can always go faster if we expend more effort, lengths and the passage of time do not change no matter how fast we move. So clearly our instincts would be built around this, and the idea of a maximum speed or people aging differently because of motion would not fit into our metal picture of "how the world is."

In the same way, an ant or an amoeba (if they were sentient) could form no concept of a spherical Earth.  They live their entire lives within perhaps a square meter of ground, where "flat ground" is the only paradigm that has any meaning in reality.

We can calculate things based on relativity, but good luck picturing or developing an intuition for them.